# Netflix Zuul route multiple IP address

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul, spring-cloud-netflix, netflix

I have Eureka service discovery and Netflix Zuul to route multiple instances of my microservice running on multiple machines. How can I add more routes in this property so that Netflix Zuul can load balance different IP addresses.

```
zuul.routes.microservice.url=http://${ip address}/8100/
```

I tried these properties from previous questions but didn't work

```
microservice.ribbon.listOfServers=http://{machine 1 address}:8100/,http://{machine 2 address}:8100/,http://localhost:8100/
microservice.ribbon.NIWSServerListClassName=com.netflix.loadbalancer.ConfigurationBasedServerList
```

Comment: Sorry did not know about this policy, thank you for informing me

Answer (score 0):

Turns out i left an important note that proved i was not load balancing by using the above properties.

https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/reference/html/#router-and-filter-zuul

Below properties worked for me

```
zuul.routes.microservice.path=/microservice/**
zuul.routes.microservice.serviceID=microservice1
microservice1.ribbon.listOfServers=http://{machine 1 ip address}:8100/,http://{machine 2 ip address}:8100/,http://localhost:8100/
microservice1.ribbon.eureka.enabled=true
```